# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading FetchApi.js:23 'data')" when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, axios

When the code runs for the first time, it's mappings data as I wanted. But when I **refresh the page** it shows an error.
Does anyone know how can I fix this error and what causes it?

> ***The code***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FetchApi = () => {

const [items, setItems] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
}, [])

async function getUser() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population');
        setItems(response.data.data)
        return items;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        {
            items.map(item => (
                <li key={item.Year}>
                    {item.Nation}
                </li>
            ))
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default FetchApi
```

> ***Output when runs for the first time***
> [image]

***Error when refresh the page***

[image]

Comment: Please try changing: `setItems(response.data.data)` to `if (response && response.data && response.data.data) setItems(response.data.data);`. It should avoid trying to access `data` if the object is undefined.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem was, "items" is undefined in its default state.
It should be

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

And I think the reason this error shows only when refresh the page was,

when I change the code and save, it changes the html view automatically but **the browser only reads the changed JavaScript codes** so the `const [items, setItems] = useState();` line never reads at first.

But when I refresh the page the code runs from the beginning and it catches that "items" is undefined and shows the error.